# Are there helper methods for STI similar to enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 introduces enums, and with it comes free helper methods. Previously, I used enums for a user role, so I had methods such as `user.manager?`, `user.employee?`, etc... However, I decided to use STI's for user roles instead. How can I create help methods for STI's similar to enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but enum is the wrong tool here. You won't get anything automagically, but your roles might be just a few so these few lines should fare well with your user model.

`class User
  %w(Mananger Employee Customer).each do |klass|
   define_method "#{klass.downcase}? do
      self.class.name == klass
    end
  end
end`

That will give you `user.manager?`

Comment: Could you explain to me why enum is the wrong tool here for roles?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that belongs in the initialize method? Is it better to check against the ``self.class.name`` or ``self.type``?

Comment: No, don't overwrite the initialize method, callbacks are much cleaner. And yes, type is an option. I'm a mongoid man myself, no idea what the sql world is doing.

Comment: Thanks! And one last thing, I'm new to Ruby meta programming, so I'm not sure if this is the same. I am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'define_method'`, and it's asking if i meant to use define_singleton_method

Comment: Uhm, what ruby are you on? `ruby --version`.
I updated the answer a little bit.

Comment: I am on ruby 2.3.3p222

Comment: I didn't know you can just run code in a class like that without having to it into the initialize method. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's in the class whereas code in the initialize method is running on an instantiated object of that class. Two very different things.